# Grizzly with TLS - Handshaking issue

Tags: java, security, ssl, grizzly

I'm currently trying to secure my Grizzly HTTP-Server with SSL (which should be quite easy according to tutorials and examples) - server side only.
So first I've downloaded the UnlimitedJCEPolicy from Orcale in order to be able to support strong TLS algorithms.
Then I've created a new keystore file with the keytool and the following command:

```
keytool -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048 -genkey -keystore .\keystore_server.jks -alias server -dname "..."
```

Finally I set up my Server with the following Java code:

```
    //Create Http Server
    HttpServer server = new HttpServer();

    //Configure and register listener
    NetworkListener adminListener = new NetworkListener("admin", "localhost", 19241);

    SSLContextConfigurator configurator = new SSLContextConfigurator();
    URL url = configurator.getClass().getResource("/keystore_server.jks");
    if(url == null) throw new Error("Could not get Keystore!");
    configurator.setKeyStoreFile(url.getFile());
    configurator.setKeyStorePass("store");
    configurator.setKeyPass("key");
    configurator.setSecurityProtocol("TLS");


    SSLContext context = configurator.createSSLContext();
    SSLEngineConfigurator engineConfigurator = new SSLEngineConfigurator(context);
    engineConfigurator.setWantClientAuth(false);
    engineConfigurator.setClientMode(true);
    engineConfigurator.setNeedClientAuth(false);


    adminListener.setSSLEngineConfig(engineConfigurator);
    adminListener.setSecure(true);

    server.addListener(adminListener);

    Endpoint endpoint = new Endpoint();

    EndpointApplication application = new EndpointApplication(endpoint);

    HttpHandler httpHandler = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(application, HttpHandler.class);
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, "/test");

    server.start();
```

Thanks to Warren, I resolved the first issue not explicitly specifying HTTPS as the protocol to use. However, there is now another problem. Here is the log:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1396054606 bytes = { 72, 223, 146, 247, 36, 165, 251, 160, 151, 23, 75, 48, 62, 242, 48, 178, 113, 150, 150, 62, 180, 118, 59, 232, 207, 168, 163, 93 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 163
'...'
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
[Raw write]: length = 168
'...'
[Raw read]: length = 5
'...'
[Raw read]: length = 171
'...'
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 171
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 1
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
```

Is anybody familiar with this type of error?

Comment: Are you specifying an https URL in the browser, as opposed to http?

Comment: Ok that was one issue for sure! I thought that this would be negotiated automatically but that was obviously not the case. However - there is still a problem, because now an Exception occurs - I pasted it at the end of my initial post

Comment: `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_*` - you need a signing cert (and private key) with ECDSA. But it should not be a problem since other cipher suites are available.

Comment: `TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV` - this might be a problem. I don't recall ever seeing anyone specify it. OpenSSL usually handles that detail based on protocol versions. Also, older servers won't be able to handle it. What version of OpenSSL is being used on the client and server?

Comment: Can you connect to the server with `openssl s_client -connect server:port -servername server -tls1`? You can include your CA cert with `-CAfile` so the command results in "Verify OK".

Comment: The error implies the server received a client hello message (message type 1, the number at the end of the SSLProtocolException line) after the server thought it was already past that point in the handshake.  That shouldn't happen unless there's a bug in the client or the server, though.  I concur with noloader's suggestion to try to open a connection on the command line using openssl.

Comment: Pls set clientMode to false: engineConfigurator.setClientMode(false);

Comment: Alexey! Thank you that was it - can you explain to me why it did not work with clientMode true?

Comment: clientMode is for client-side connections, you're on the server-side :)

Comment: Ah okay so I would use client mode if I would use the SSLEngine to connect to a server secured with SSL

Comment: yes (I need to add more symbols to post a comment :))

Comment: @jww EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV: OP is using Java JSSE not OpenSSL. OpenSSL initially sends only the SCSV so there's no option to specify; JSSE supports both the (empty) extension and the SCSV, but defaults to the SCSV, which works *better* with old servers than the extension, as described in RFC 5746.

Comment: What packages are you using for Endpoint and EndpointApplication?  My IDE (NetBeans 8.1) is not finding a compatible (with parameters used) Endpoint class, and not finding anything implementing Endpoint.  I'm having the same problem--trying to get Grizzly (embedded in the standalone Tyrus/Grizzly WebSocket implementation of JSR 356) to run a secure "wss" endpoint instead of ignoring the fact that the URI is for "wss" and deciding to use "ws" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same problem, when using `-Djavax.net.debug=all` command line parameter I found this log line:

```
Grizzly(2) SelectorRunner, fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
```

Based on the comments by alexey I changed the code to:

```
engineConfigurator.setClientMode(false);
engineConfigurator.setNeedClientAuth(false);
```

After this change, the fatal error dissapears and I am able to access the application.wadl over https with a browser.

I've lost quite a bit of time searching for a solution, it would be nice if Grizzly reported this problem in a more readable, understandable way.