# AES-PSK authentification using grizzly

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, grizzly, cumulocity

I have already developed a grizzly-based-HTTP-Server. In order to test my Server I also developed a grizzly-based-Client, which can comunicate with my Server using http-Messages. I instantiate my http-Server using grizzly as following:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
server.addListener(new NetworkListener("server","127.0.01",8081);
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new Handler());

try {
    server.start();
    Thread.currentThread().join();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I want to secure the communication between them. When I am searching for Informations about possible implementation of ssl in grizzly, I found this **link** [SSL with Grizzly and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098105/ssl-with-grizzly-and-jersey).  I noticed that I should use **SSLContextConfigurator** combined with **Jersey**. This means for me that I must modify my grizzly based Server, which is totally based on grizzly. Before doing this step, I must be sure that I can implement my AES-preshared-key using Jersey Combined with grizzly. Till now I found no example that Shows how to use  AES-preshared-key in Java.

According to my readings about preshared-key-method, I knew that I should use javax.crypto.Cipher. Now I am confused about adding this functinality(ssl with preshared key) to my Server. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `SSLEngineConfigurator` [docs](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/ssl/SSLEngineConfigurator.html#enabledCipherSuites)? You can add TLS v1.2 ciphers from [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) to `enabledCipherSuites` in your ssl configuration. That page also gives you the list including compatibility with different JDK versions.

[This](https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/tree/2.3.x/samples/framework-samples/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/samples/ssl) should give you an idea how to proceed with SSL using Grizzly.

Comment: yes I checked SSLEngineConfigurator docs. What I know is that PSK ciphers are not supported. I looked in the list you provide me. Unfortunately, It is not supported. I will use certificates. Thank you for the example combining SSL and Grizzly